# Passing array parameter to a scheduled script from a suitelet - SuiteScript

Tags: parameter-passing, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a suitelet which is creating an array called POdata- this is logging correctly on the suitelet.  I want to pass the array to a scheduled script and then perform additional functions.   I #think# I am doing this correctly based upon other similar questions - but the log data for the scheduled script is blank.

Here is the Suitelet:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/search','N/runtime', 'N/task'], 

function(serverWidget, search, runtime, task) {
    
    function getPurchaseOrders() {
        var purchaseOrders = search.create({
            type: "purchaseorder",
            filters:
           [
              ["type","anyof","PurchOrd"], 
              "AND", 
              ["createdfrom.type","anyof","SalesOrd"], 
              "AND", 
              ["trandate","within","01/30/2023"], 
              "AND", 
              ["mainline","is","T"]
           ],
           columns:
           [
              "trandate",
              "entity",
              "createdfrom"
           ]
        });
        return purchaseOrders;
    }

    
    
    function onRequest(context) {
        var request = context.request;
        var response = context.response;

       if (context.request.method === 'GET') {
            var form = serverWidget.createForm({ title: 'Drop Ship Purchase Orders' });
            
            form.addSubmitButton({ label: 'Submit!' });
            
            var sublist = form.addSublist({
                id: 'custpage_purchase_orders',
                type: serverWidget.SublistType.LIST,
                label: 'Drop Ship Purchase Orders'
            });
            // Show a 'Mark All' button
            sublist.addMarkAllButtons();            
            // Add a checkbox to mark which records should be processed
            var printField = sublist.addField({
                id: 'custpage_rec_process',
                label: 'Process',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX
            });
            // Add an internalid to track the line item
            var idField = sublist.addField({
                id: 'custpage_rec_id',
                label: 'Internal ID',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
            });
            sublist.addField({
                id: 'custpage_trandate',
                label: 'Date',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.DATE
            })
            sublist.addField({
                id: 'custpage_name',
                label: 'Vendor Name',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
            })
            sublist.addField({
                id: 'custpage_salesorder',
                label: 'Sales Order',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.TEXT
            })
            
            var purchaseOrders = getPurchaseOrders(); // <—— HERE
            var counter = 0;
            purchaseOrders.run().each(function(result) {
                log.debug("result", result);
                var poDate = result.getValue('trandate');
                var vendorName = result.getText('entity');
                var sOrder = result.getValue('createdfrom');
                sublist.setSublistValue({
                    id: 'custpage_trandate',
                    line: counter,
                    value: poDate
                });
                sublist.setSublistValue({
                    id: 'custpage_name',
                    line: counter,
                    value: vendorName
                });
                sublist.setSublistValue({
                    id: 'custpage_salesorder',
                    line: counter,
                    value: sOrder
                });
                counter++;
                return true;
            })
            context.response.writePage(form);
            }  else if (request.method === 'POST') {
                
            var POdata = [];
            var lineCount = request.getLineCount('custpage_purchase_orders');
    
            for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; i++) {
                var Vendor = request.getSublistValue({
                    group: 'custpage_purchase_orders',
                    name: 'custpage_name',
                    line: i
                }); // "F"
                 var process = request.getSublistValue({
                    group: 'custpage_purchase_orders',
                    name: 'custpage_rec_process',
                    line: i
                });
                var soID = request.getSublistValue({
                    group: 'custpage_purchase_orders',
                    name: 'custpage_salesorder',
                    line: i
                }); // "value 1"

                
                POdata.push({
                    'Vendor : Vendor,
                    'Process?' : process,
                    'SO Internal ID' : soID
                    });
                
            }
             log.debug('data', POdata);
            
        var scriptTask = task.create({
          taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT,
          scriptId: 'customscriptatempschedule',
          deploymentId: 'customdeployatempschedule',
           params: {
            custscript_PO_data: JSON.stringify(POdata)
          }
          });
          var scriptTaskId = scriptTask.submit();
          log.debug('scriptTaskId', scriptTaskId);
      }
            
        }
    }

    return {
        onRequest: onRequest
    };

});
```

Here is the Scheduled Script:

```
/**
 *  
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
 
 define(['N/runtime', 'N/record', 'N/search', 'N/config', 'N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/redirect', 'N/url'],
 
 function(runtime, record, search, config, serverWidget, redirect, url) {
    
    function execute(context) {
        
        try{
            var getParameter = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name: 'custscript_PO_data'});
            
            log.debug('getParameter', getParameter);            
        } 
        catch(error)
        {log.debug('error',error);}
        }
        
    return{execute:execute}
});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- make sure your parameter is defined as type LongText
- try using all lowercase versions of your parameter names e.g. `custscript_po_data`

Comment: thank you.. I did figure out I had the parameter defined on the wrong script. I had it on the suitelet NOT on the scheduled script.   Once I fixed that.. it worked!